# forloop continue again after end of the iteration

Tags: php, for-loop

I used function with same logic given below
   Given below code is sample of same logic i used, i need to continue the for loop after end of the iteration, i assign 0 to the variable $j at end so forloop need to continue, why its closed the process.

```
for($i=$j;$i<7;$i++){

echo "<br/>".$i;
if($i == 6){$j=0;continue;}
}
```

Actual Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Expected output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6 
1
2
3
4
5
6 
.....etc
```

My Original code sample is

```
 foreach($Qry_Rst as $key=>$Rst_Val){
   for($j=$ItrDt;$j<7;$j++){
     $ItrDate =  date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day + $j, $year));
                if($ItrDate == $Rst_Val['sloat_day']){
                  $TimeTableAry[$loop_itr] = $Rst_Val;
                   break
                 }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc says](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

> The first expression (expr1) is evaluated (executed) once unconditionally at the beginning of the loop.

So instead of `$j` just use `$i` to reset the loop. As this ([demo](http://codepad.org/lkyxq2np))

```
$j = 1;
$current = 0;
for ($i=$j; $i<4; $i++) {
    printf("i: %d, j: %d\n", $i, $j);
    if ($i==3 && $current < 5) {
        $i = -1;
        $j = mt_rand(0,3);
        $current++;
        continue;
    }
}
```

shows, you actually need to reset `$i = -1;` so it will be `0` after `$i++` will be evaluated.

---

But with this you'll have an `if` in every iteration of the loop although you only need it for one. Basically you don't need it for the iteration itself but only to start a next one, so there must be something else here.

```
function doFor($data, $callback) {
    $dataLength = count($data);
    for ($i=0; $i<$dataLength; $i++) {
        call_user_func($callback, $data[$i]);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Isolating the loop into its own function will allow for one line that will execute the wanted [`callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) allowing your main code to be something like ([demo](http://codepad.org/NE9QwFS4))

```
$data = array(array("foo","bar"),array("hello"),array("world","!"));

function justDump($obj) {
    var_dump($obj);
};

$i = 0;
do {
    $data = doFor($data, 'justDump');
    print "<br>";
    $i++;
} while($i<5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the way you originally wanted (only slightly edited):

```
//counter to avoid infinite loop
$counter = 0;
for($i=$i;$i<7;$i++){
    echo "<br/>".$i;
    if($i == 6){
        $i=0; 
        $counter++; 
        continue;
    }
    if($counter == 5){break;}
}

1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
...
```